# Is matrix diagonizable if degree of minimal polynomial is n

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I have been stuck at the following problem:

Let $V$ be the $n$-dimensional vector space over field $\mathbb{C}$, and $\phi$ - linear transformation. Then prove, that if the degree of minimal polynomial of $\phi$ is $n$, than  all of eigenvalues are distinct.

I came with a thing, that we can prove, that $\phi$ is diagonizable, than by the fact, that  if matrix is diagonizable, than the minimal polynomial is $(\lambda - \lambda_1)^{s_1}...(\lambda - \lambda_k)^{s_k}$, where $s_1 = ... = s_k = 1, k <= n$, the $\phi$ will have distinct eigenvalues. But I dont know how to prove this and ask your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is not true. Consider, for example, the linear map $\phi:\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}^2$ given by the matrix $\;\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 1\\ 0& \lambda\end{pmatrix}$. The minimal polynomial of $\phi$ is $m_{\phi}(t) = (t - \lambda)^2$, but $\lambda$ is the only eigenvalue of $\phi$.